# Why $h\phi (x)$ is analog to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm reading Lang's: *Calculus of Several Variables.* Here:

[image]

[image]

And comparing the two formulas:

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=h\phi (x) - hg(x)$$

$$f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k - |H|g(H)$$

He does an analogy with the purpose of how to build the derivative for $2$ variables. I can understand/especulate why $hg(x)$ and $|H|g(H)$ are analog: If I take one coordinate vectors, then I guess $|(h)|=h$ and hence, it's just a norm in disguise. My problem is that I have no clue on why $h\phi (x)$ is analog to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}h+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}k $, specially why there are $k,h$ in there?

Comment: You are changing two variables. The $h$ represents the change in the $x$ direction and $k$ represents the change in the $y$ direction.

Comment: The term ${\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} h + {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} k$ is the 'best' linear approximation to $f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)$ at $(x,y)$. Look at $(h,k) \mapsto {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x} h + {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y} k$ as a linear map on the 'perturbations' $(h,k)$. This is more obvious if you write it as $(h,k) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial x}  & {\partial f(x,y) \over \partial y}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} h \\ k\end{bmatrix} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it! It was really silly, I just took an example and it cleared things a bit. I took $f(x,y)=xy$ and wrote:

$$f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)=(x+h)(y+k)-xy=xk+hy+hk$$

And hence:

$$\left[ \frac{\partial f}{dx}h+\frac{\partial f}{dy}k=yh+xk\right]\sim [xk+hy+hk]$$

Now it feels more natural to accept that.